# wordpress get products by meta data and meta value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to display products by meta value and meta key. I am using the code below to validate the meta_key and meta_value. Now if there are no meta_keys with the value "yes_feat" no products print. Which is great!

The problem is, if there is only 1 product that has the meta_keys with the value "yes_feat" all the other products print as well. How do I make it so only the products with the meta_value "yes_feat" display

```
        $params = array(

            'post_type' => 'product',  
            'meta_key' => '_featured',  
            'meta_value' => 'yes_feat',  
            'posts_per_page' => 5 

        );
        $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
        global $post, $product;

        if ($wc_query->have_posts()) { 
            // i am only trying to print products with meta_value = yes_feat
            // but if the statement above is true it prints all products
             echo "print products that have meta_value = yes_feat";
        }   
        else 
        {
            echo "nothing found";
        }
```

Thanks alot

Comment: Your code seems to be ok. It can't give all products if there is not additional factor there.  With this code print your final query inside have_posts loop and paste the result here. $i=0; if ($wc_query->have_posts()) { $i++;  if ($i==1)   var_dump($wc_query->query); }

Answer (score 6):

**add meta query in WP_Query argument**

```
<?php
$params = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array('key' => '_featured', //meta key name here
              'value' => 'yes_feat', 
              'compare' => '=',
        )
    ),  
    'posts_per_page' => 5 

);
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
global $post, $product;

if( $wc_query->have_posts() ) {

  while( $wc_query->have_posts() ) {

    $wc_query->the_post();

        $wc_query->post_name;
        echo "print products that have meta_value = yes_feat";
        $yes_feat = get_post_meta($wc_query->ID, '_featured',true );
  } // end while

} // end if
 else 
{
    echo "nothing found";
}

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```